# SQL query to get hierarchical tree folder structure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have tables as follows

file_table

```
f_id  file_name
 21     abc.xml
 13     xyz.xml
```

folder_table

```
f_id   f_name
 15     Main
 21     Sub
 13     Sub2
```

group_table

```
parent  child
 21      13
 15      21
```

In `file_table`, `file_name` "xyz.xml" and its corresponding `f_id` is 13(sub2) based on this `f_id` i want check its parent node from the `group_table` i.e 21(sub). and then check is there coresponding parent node from previous parent node in `group_table` i.e 15(Main) and so on. finally check this parent node exists in `child` if it is not exists that is root node. `13 -> 21 -> 15` 
I want to write a query to select data like below.

```
f_name           file_name
Main/Sub/Sub2     xyz.xml
Main/Sub          abc.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (CTE) in your query to get all the directories in a file's path. In your main query, you can (ab)use a [`SELECT ... FOR XML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server) subquery to concatenate all those directories into a full path.

```sql
WITH CTE (f_id, depth, f_id_depth) AS (
  --Anchor statement
  --(This provides the starting result set of the CTE.)
  SELECT DISTINCT
    f_id,
    1,
    f_id
  FROM
    file_table
  UNION ALL
  --Recursive statement
  --(Note this contains the CTE itself in the FROM-clause.)
  --(This statement gets executed repeatedly until it returns no rows anymore.)
  --(Each time, its results are added to the CTE's result set.)
  SELECT
    CTE.f_id,
    CTE.depth + 1,
    F.f_id
  FROM
    CTE
    INNER JOIN group_table AS G ON G.child = CTE.f_id_depth
    INNER JOIN folder_table AS F ON F.f_id = G.parent
)
SELECT
  --Use a SELECT ... FOR XML subquery to concatenate the folder names (each prefixed with a slash) in a single string.
  --Additionally, wrap the subquery in a STUFF function to remove the leading slash.
  STUFF((SELECT '/' + FF.f_name
         FROM CTE INNER JOIN folder_table AS FF ON FF.f_id = CTE.f_id_depth
         WHERE CTE.f_id = F.f_id
         ORDER BY CTE.depth DESC
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS f_name,
  F.file_name
FROM
  file_table AS F;
```